# Compilation Error when using maven 2 and trying to compile Eclipse plug-ins

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, maven-2, eclipse-rcp

I have an eclipse plugin that has been around for a while. We have always built the plugin manually. I am trying to automate the build process. So first I added maven 2 and now I have the pom.xml and I right clicking my project and doing Run As -> maven... and then i put in clean install as seen below. Ignore the error, I changed the basedirectory to not include some sensitive information.

[image]

Now I am seeing this:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] myProject/src/com/myCompany/is/dt/eclipse/wizards/build/Somewizard.java:[5,34] package org.eclipse.core.resources does not exist
```

There are more errors besides this. But I have all of these packages in eclipse. I just need to make maven 2 point at them some how. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you added those dependencies to your pom file? (Are you really using Maven2? If so stop it...) Start using Maven 3.X

Comment: I think it is actually M2Eclipse. But I guess not, I auto-generated the pom.xml with eclipse. I guess that does not add the needed packages too.